# Keeping switch button checked when after back button, when app is closed/restarted etc

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a fragment of installed apps in a listview with a switch button next to it.

[image]

What I am trying to do is when the user hits the button and it is on, I want it to stay on when the user goes back, exits the app or restarts the activity.

I have done research and I know this is implementable but I am not sure how to achieve this.

[Listview : How to remain highlighted/selected after press back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893171/listview-how-to-remain-highlighted-selected-after-press-back-button)

I tried following this but it was not successful.

Here is my adapter class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;



    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];


    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        Switch ck1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1= (Switch)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);




        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        //What would I put here!?!?

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    Log.i("This is", " checked: " + position);

                }

                else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    Log.i("This is", " not checked: " + position);

                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }




}
```

Here is my InstalledAppActivity fragment class:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;



public class InstalledAppActivity extends Fragment
        implements OnItemClickListener {




    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_installed, container, false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();


        /*To filter out System apps*/

        apkList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applist);

        new LoadApplications(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).execute();


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the given PackageInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @param pkgInfo
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }

    private boolean isSystemPackage1(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) ? false
                : true;
    }


// Don't need in Fragment
/*@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
   // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}*/

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //ApkAdapter apkAdapter=(ApkAdapter)apkList.getAdapter();

    }


    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Context mContext;

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        public LoadApplications(Context context){
            Context mContext = context;
        }




        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                    .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);


          /*  List<ApplicationInfo> list = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);


            for(int n = 0;n<list.size();n++){
                if ((list.get(n).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP))
            }*/


            for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
                boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
                boolean c = isSystemPackage1(pi);

                if(!b || !c ) {
                    packageList1.add(pi);
                }
            }

            //sort by application name

            final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

            Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs) {
                    return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
                }
            });



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InstalledAppActivity.this.getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading your apps...");
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));

            if (pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }



}
```

I am trying to figure out what modifications I need to make in order to keeping the switch buttons checked when after back button is hit, when app is closed/restarted etc.

EDIT:

I am getting an error in

holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1= (Switch)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);




        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    Log.i("This is", " checked: " + position);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("checkBox1", true);
                    editor.commit();

                }

                else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    Log.i("This is", " not checked: " + position);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("checkBox1", false);
                    editor.commit();

                }
            }
        });

        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));




        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: Look into `SharedPreferences`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: where did you get `NameOfThingToSave` from, and why don't you use `checkBox1` as you did 5 lines earlier ? (same goes for the name of the pref)

Comment: I did that in my code but when I scroll down the buttons automatically get checked

Answer (score 3):

A common way of storing the state of certain objects in android is related to SharedPreferences. You basically store key-value pair in a dedicated file for your application. Within your activity most reasonably on its onDestroy() method you may store the state of a button as follows:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                           "file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("BUTTON_SELECTED", true);
editor.commit();
```

you can persist the state of the same button similarly reasonably within the onCreate() method of your activity as follows:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                               "file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isButtonSelected = prefs.getBoolean("BUTTON_SELECTED", false);
```

and you can then set the last state of that particular button;

Comment: you can do that in your adapter as you have access to the ApplicationContext. however, these are expensive IO operations so you need to pay attention on the time when to call them.